# I got an error while loop statement in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

My statement with While Loop got an error which showing me the error is in class

```
batchsize = 10
train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(train, batchsize)
max_epoch = 90
studyThreshold = 1
needStudy = True

try:            
    while(train_iter.epoch < max_epoch) and needStudy:
        train_batch = train_iter.next()
        x, t = concat_examples(train_batch)
        print(t)
        y = model(x)
        loss = F.mean_squared_error(y, t)
        model.cleargrads()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.update()
        if train_iter.is_new_epoch:
            print("epoch", train_iter.epoch, "loss=", loss.data, end=" ")
            loss_X.append(train_iter.epoch)
            loss_Y.append(loss.data)
except Exception as e: # replaced with Exception to handle other errors
    print('except :',type(e))
```

and the output is exception :

```
except : <class 'KeyError'>
```

Note: I am using Pandas Package

The whole error I got

```
except : <class 'KeyError'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 33617

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-7a80e54a4aea> in <module>
     35     while((train_iter.epoch < max_epoch) and needStudy):
---> 36         train_batch = train_iter.next()
     37         x, t = concat_examples(train_batch)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chainer\iterators\serial_iterator.py in __next__(self)
     76 
---> 77         batch = [self.dataset[index] for index in indices]
     78         return batch

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chainer\iterators\serial_iterator.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     76 
---> 77         batch = [self.dataset[index] for index in indices]
     78         return batch

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
```

Comment: Can you paste full stack trace? On which line you got error?

Comment: @vb_rises the whole error pasted above

Comment: what is train_iter? paste more code.

Comment: @vb_rises pasted more code

Comment: it works if you change it to `train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(train.T, batchsize)` but then not sure about other logic. You might need to change other logic accordingly. But it is very strange that it gives this error. Or may be some bug.

Comment: @vb_rises why it used `.T` ?

Comment: @vb_rises i think i found the error .. epoch is not running well with the code. So epoch is in chainer package which means the problem is related to chainer package.

Comment: .next() is trying to find next batch. For example, let's say that it is trying to find next batch of 10 records from 1 to 10. So ideally it should search index 1 to 10, but instead it is searching columns with names 1 to 10, so if you do Transpose, then index becomes columns and no error in .next() method. And yes, removing .epoch works fine. So better way is to remove .epoch.